# Delete rows that have duplicate values in few selected columns but need to leave one of the rows out

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, duplicates

I need a SQL Server T-SQL query to delete rows with duplicate values in selected columns but don’t delete all the duplicates; make those duplicates become unique rows.

Can someone please help me?

I used `DISTINCT`, `FILTER`, `HAVING`, etc but it didn't work out.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and you attempt.